# "At Most" Probability Combination Problem

Tags: probability, combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, combinations

In a class of 25 students, 12 are mathematics majors and 8 history majors. A group of 5 students is chosen at random from this class. What is the probability the group has at most 2 mathematics majors?

I believe that result is as follows:

(13C5* 12C0 + 12C1* 13C4 + 12C2 * 13C3) / 25C5

but the result seems too high. Any suggestions?

Comment: It looks right to me.  Roughly half the class is mathematics majors so a fair fraction of the possibilities should include everything up to half of the group comprising mathematics majors.  My guess would be that's roughly $\frac 13$ of the possibilities, but your formula looks correct.

Comment: my result is 0.5408

Comment: Upon reflection, the answer has to be more than half.  The combinations where mathematics students are less than half of the group have to outnumber the combinations where mathematics students are more than half of the group because mathematics students are less than half the group.

Comment: Thank you for the reassurance.

Comment: Your solution is correct.